# MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification works in iOS 5 but not in iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, notifications, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to play a video with an MPMoviePlayerViewController. So in my view controller I register as an observer for `MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification`.

I then initialise the MPMoviePlayerViewController:

```
self.mPlayerVC = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"<videoURL>"]];
```

and wait for the notification to arrive. When it does I execute this code:

```
MPMoviePlayerController* playerController = notification.object;

if ([playerController loadState] & MPMovieLoadStatePlayable) {
    if (self.mPlayerVC) {
        [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.mPlayerVC];
    }
}
```

Anyone an idea why this works for iOS 5 but not for iOS 6? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in iOS 6' MediaPlayer.framework. To get the video to play I call `prepareToPlay` after initialising the MPMoviePlayerViewController

```
self.mPlayerVC = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"<videoURL>"]];
[self.mPlayerVC.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
```

Now the notifications come in again but the app crashes when I call `[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.mPlayerVC];` in the method that is called for the `MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification`.

To prevent the crash replace

```
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.mPlayerVC];
```

with something like

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)]) {
[self presentViewController:self.mPlayerVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentModalViewController:animated:)]) {
[self presentModalViewController:self.mPlayerVC animated:YES];
}
```